# Create RDLC report using Stored Procedure in WindowsApplication C#

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

What steps do I need to make a report using a stored procedure that has parameters? The stored procedure is `showAccount` and has 2 parameters, `@maxBalance` and `@minBalance`.

How to call the stored procedure and display the results to RDLC report?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on a couple of things: are you using Entity Framework, or just ADO.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Local reports can not use stored procedures. You will have to query the database yourself and pass a data set to the report. This is in constrast to server reports, which query their data themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Summary of steps you need to perform,

1. First you need to create your RDLC report in Visual Studio by using add new Report
2. You need to create new DataSource for the stored procedure. When you add new data source, it will ask for the connection string and the database object to be used in the data source. You can select your stored procedure.
3. Bind the data source to the report.
4. Design your report, table, column etc.
5. Call the report from your windows application like [this](http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-create-rdlc-report-in-c-windows.html#.U6mJViyKBeh)